# Argument is not numeric error while comparing hash values based on keys

Tags: perl, hash

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use warnings;
my @mdsum;

open (IN1,"$ARGV[0]") || die "counldn't open";
open (MYFILE, '>>md5sum-problem.txt');
open (IN2, "mdsumfile.txt");
my %knomexl=();
my %knomemdsum = ();
my @arrfile ;
my $tempkey ;
my $tempval ;
my @values ;
my $val;
my $i;
my @newarra;
my $testxl ;
my $testmdsum;
while(<IN1>){
    next if /barcode/;
    @arrfile = split('\t', $_);
    $knomexl{$arrfile[0]} = $arrfile[2];
}

while(<IN2>){
    chomp $_;
    @newarra = split(/ {1,}/, $_);
    $tempval = $newarra[0];
    $tempkey = $newarra[1];
    $tempkey=~ s/\t*$//g;
    $tempval=~ s/\s*$//g;
    $tempkey=~s/.tar.gz//g;
    $knomemdsum{$tempkey} = $tempval;
}

@values = keys %knomexl;

foreach $i(@values){
    $testxl = $knomexl{$values[$i]};
    print $testxl."\n";
    $testmdsum = $knomemdsum{$values[$i]};
    print $testmdsum."\n";

    if ( $testxl ne $testmdsum ) {
        if ($testxl ne ""){
            print MYFILE "Files hasving md5sum issue $i\n";
        }
    }
}
close (MYFILE);
```

I have two files one both having File name and Mdsum values and I need to check that which all file's md5sum values are not matching so I understand that in some case where Value and corresponding values will not be their and I want those cases only. Any work around on this code ? Please. This code is pretty simple but don't know why it's not working!! :( :(

Answer (score 1):

```
 @values = keys %knomexl;

     foreach $i(@values){
        #print Dumper $knomexl{$values[$i]};
        $testxl = $knomexl{$i};
        print $testxl."\n";
        $testmdsum = $knomemdsum{$i};
        print $testmdsum."\n";
```

`$i` is an element of `@values` because of the `foreach`, not an index, so you shouldn't use `$values[$i]`.

Comment: A better suggestion would just be `foreach (keys %knomexl) { $knomexl{$_} }`.

Comment: @squiguy That's a stylistic choice, not really important for solving the problem.